# Code in Perl for pi calculation

Tags: perl

Could someone explain step by step this code in Perl:

```
$.=.5;
$\=2/$.++-$\for$...1e6;
print
```

Answer (score 12):

Add white space:

```
$. = .5;
$\ = (2 / $.++) - $\ for $. .. 1e6;
```

Substitute with saner var names:

```
$x = .5;
$pi = (2 / $x++) - $pi for $x .. 1e6;
```

Don't use the same var for two purposes:

```
$x = .5;
$pi = (2 / $x++) - $pi for 0 .. 1e6;
```

Convert to formula:

```
pi = 2/1000000.5 - ( ... - (2/2.5 - (2/1.5 - (2/0.5))))

   = 2/1000000.5 - ... + 2/2.5 - 2/1.5 + 2/0.5

   = 4/2000001 - ... + 4/5 - 4/3 + 4/1

   = 4/1 - 4/3 + 4/5 - ... + 4/2000001
```

which is [listed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) in Wikipedia as the Gregory–Leibniz series.

`print;` is `print($_);`, which prints `$_` (unused, so undef, which stringifies to empty string) followed by `$\` (which is normally an empty string, but is used as the accumulator in the original code).

Comment: You did not explain the single 'print'.

Comment: clear, upvote, and I think this should be added into your post.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start first by breaking the code down into something more readable with some white-space.  White space is relatively unimportant in Perl.

```
$. = .5;
$\ = 2 / $.++ - $\ for $. .. 1e6;
print
```

This code is making use of Perl's special built-in global variables to make things look short (`man perlvar` for more details on the specific variables this code is using).  Let's make it more readable by replacing them with names that are human readable.

```
$denominator = .5;
$pi = 2 / $denominator++ - $pi for $denominator .. 1e6
print $pi
```

And just to help, let's move the inline for loop into a more verbose loop.

```
$denominator = .5;
foreach my $i ($denominator .. 1e6) {
  $pi = 2 / $denominator - $pi;
  $denominator += 1;
}
print $pi
```

So, this makes it a bit easier to decipher, and it's a standard convergence routine for calculating pi.  There's a number of [different ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Continued_fractions), but basically, if you step through it, you'll see that it converges to the famous 3.14159...  The denominator is okay to use as the first element of the sequence generator because it will floor to the integer 0.

```
Pass 1: 2 / 0.5 - 0 = 4
Pass 2: 2 / 1.5 - 4 = -2.666...
Pass 3: 2 / 2.5 - (-2.666...) = 3.4666...
Pass 4: 2 / 3.5 - 3.4666... = -2.895...
Pass 5: 2 / 4.5 - (-2.895...) = 3.339...
```

You get the idea.  The code runs through 1,000,001 passes to reach the final approximation.  As long as it runs an odd number of approximations, it should converge to pi (even numbered approximations converge to negative pi).

The reason the print statement works is that `$\` is the output record separator.  `print` by itself will print `$_`, the default variable, which will be empty.  The value of pi will be in the `$\` value, which will effectively be the line ending, so it prints out a blank value followed by the calculated value of pi (no traditional line ending).

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's a beauty. Someone was trying to make that look as convoluted as possible. Here's a more readable version:

```
my $pi = 0;
for (my $i=0.5; $i < 1e6+1; $i++)
{
    $pi=2/$i - $pi;
}
print $pi."\n";
```

This is the mathematical representation of the [*Gregory-Leibnitz Formula*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80)

The original version uses a few [Perl special variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) to confuse you. The `$.` is entirely unnecessary here and purely for obfuscation. The `$\` is the **output record separator**. That means this variable will be appended after a `print` statement. Therefore, the single `print` at the end simply prints the result of the calculation that was stored in `$\`. Finally, the code uses a post-fix `for` loop and the `..` operator instead of the more explicit for loop in my version. I hope that clears things up a bit.

Comment: `for my $i (0..1e6) { ... 2/($i+0.5) ...}` is simpler than `for (my $i=0.5; $i < 1e6+1; $i++) { ... 2/$i ...}`

Comment: @ikegami arguably so. My main point was to make the for loop explicit a-la C or Java, to avoid the - potentially - confusing `..` syntax. But in the end, it really depends on what part of the code the OP didn't understand :-)

Comment: My point was the opposite; that C-style loops are awful. They are so complex, that we either need to wade through nine operators, or make assumptions as to what those operators are. Both are very bad compared option compared to a counting loop (`for (1..5)`)'s two operators. It's not "potentionally confusing"; it's prime example of clarity! Potentionally confusing is having to hunt a symbol-dense line to see if `<` if followed by `=` (and the very fact that one hunts for that means one is making assumptions about what's around). Potentionally confusing is non-standard start bounds. etc.

Comment: Don't get me wrong: I agree on the point. But for someone who's never been exposed to Perl or doesn't now the peculiarities of the language well, the `..` operator might be less familiar than the - ugly - `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

This can be rewritten as:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $divisor = 0.5;
my $pi = 0;
for my $i (0..1e6)
{
    $pi = 2 / $divisor++ - $pi
}
print "$pi\n";
```

So it uses some mathematical series expansion to calculate pi (See @ikegami's answer)

Comment: Technically, it only did `print $pi;` rather than `print "$pi\n";`.

Comment: @ikegami: true, but not printing the trailing newline messes up my prompt :)